# Can't run Pocketsphinx script at boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyaudio, pocketsphinx

I am making a smart mirror with a voice interface on the Raspberry Pi. There are two separate scripts, one for voice control and one for a GUI. I am trying to launch both of them when the RPi boots up. The problem is that only the GUI script boots up. I can run the SR script manually from terminal, but I can't launch it automatically. So far I have tried:

-launching with crontab

-launching with rc.local

-starting one script from the other with OS.SYSTEM

-starting one script from the other with POPEN

-starting one script from the other with a bash script

-launching at boot with a bash script

-launching only after LXDE is loaded

-launching a separate script that launches both of them

Every scenario just sends the script into an infinite error loop.
Below is the simplified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import environ, path, system
import pyaudio
import time
import sys
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *


MODELDIR = "pocketsphinx/model"
DATADIR = "pocketsphinx/test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'MERLIN/MERLINv3.lm'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'MERLIN/MERLINv3.dic'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')

decoder = Decoder(config)

def getKWord():
    try:
        stream.start_stream() 
        in_speech_bf = False
        decoder.start_utt()
        while True:
            buf = stream.read(4096)
            if buf:
                decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
                if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
                    in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
                    if not in_speech_bf:
                        decoder.end_utt()
                        stream.stop_stream()
                        #system('mpg321 /home/pi/MERLIN_main/process_sounds/Beep_low.mp3')
                        return str(decoder.hyp().hypstr)
                        system('mpg321 /home/pi/MERLIN_main/process_sounds/Beep_low.mp3')

            else:
                decoder.end_utt()
                stream.stop_stream()
                print('PocketSphinx could not decode')
                return "Pocketsphinx could not decode. Try again"
        decoder.end_utt()
    except:
        print('PocketSphinx had an error')
        return "Oops. Pocketsphinx had an error"


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=4096)
try:
    print ("say something")
    while True:
        kword=getKWord()
        system('mpg321 /home/pi/MERLIN_main/process_sounds/Beep_hi.mp3')
        # do stuff
        time.sleep(.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

The error is in getKWord(), and is [Errno -9988] Stream Closed

The loop just spits that out over and over.
I know it's not a code problem because it runs without issue for days at a time when I launch it with Terminal. I just can't get it to launch on boot.
So far nothing has worked. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You need to specify an absolute path for the model folder.

Comment: You asked the same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447878/unable-to-launch-two-scripts-at-boot

Comment: Thank you Nicolay. I will try that now. I did ask the same thing, but I didn't know what was causing the infinite loop at that time. Once I had more information, I asked a new question but thought I deleted the old question before posting this one.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Unfortunately that did not work. Adding the full path to the model folder had no effect

Comment: The second thing to try is https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-make-pulseaudio-run-once-at-boot-for-all-your-users